# F# match with ->

Tags: f#, nemerle

I want to make something like it (Nemerle syntax)

```
def something =
match(STT)
    | 1 with st= "Summ"
    | 2 with st= "AVG" =>
        $"$st : $(summbycol(counter,STT))"
```

on F# so is it real with F#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you'd like to assign some value to a variable as part of the pattern. There is no direct support for this in F#, but you can define a parameterized active pattern that does that:

```
let (|Let|) v e = (v, e)

match stt with 
| Let "Summ" (st, 1) 
| Let "AVG" (st, 2) -> srintf "%s ..." st
```

The string after `Let` is a parameter of the pattern (and is passed in as value of `v`). The pattern then returns a tuple containing the bound value and the original value (so you can match the original value in the second parameter of the tuple.

Comment: One thing I've learned about F#: active patterns can do anything :)

Comment: @Juliet: Yeah, they are really powerful.

Answer (score 13):

There is no direct support for that but you can mimic the effect like this as well:

```
let 1, st, _ | 2, _, st = stt, "Summ", "AVG"
sprintf "%s %a" st summbycol (counter, stt)
```

Comment: Very interesting: you can use pattern matching with alternatives, without using the `match` or `function` keywords. I wonder whether this is an official feature?

Comment: @wmeyer: This is very much an official feature. The idea that patterns only appear after `match` or `function` expressions is a common misconception. Function arguments are also patterns so you can write `let f((a, b), (c, d)) = ..`. This is one of the biggest advancements ML made over Lisp.

Comment: @aneccodeal Vanilla OCaml. Try `let 1, st, _ | 2, _, st = 1, "Summ", "AVG";;` and `let 1, st, _ | 2, _, st = 2, "Summ", "AVG";;`.

Comment: @JonHarrop any chance how to get rid off the warning? "stdin(2,5): warning FS0025: Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, the value '(0,_,_)' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s)."

Comment: @stej You probably want to replace the literal `2` pattern with the catchall `_` in the second half of the or-pattern.